# Switching from Kali to Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My Kali has just stopped working. I don't know what's causing the issue but it's a big one. I'd like to switch from Kali to Ubuntu because of it, but the problem is that my tower won't recognize my USB has Ubuntu loaded into it both the ISO and unzipped files have been tried. I'm not sure what to do about it now. I tried uninstalling kali-linux-full and kali-menu and etc and reinstalling but that never fixed it.

The issue with my Kali is the Desktop. When I check properties of a file on Desktop, it freezes the Desktop. I can still use Terminal and other things but they're extremely slow. It just kind of happened out of nowhere. My best guess is an update broke it and my hardware isn't compatible.

TL;DR I want Ubuntu instead of Kali but Ubuntu isn't recognized on my USB. What do I do?

Comment: I've done a edit to your question - lets try to keep profanity out of our questions please.

Comment: Does kali have a debootstrap package?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I'm not extremely linux experienced.

Comment: Something I've noticed is my terminal grabs things from lists in my sources.list that doesn't exist in the file. And its grabbing things for the wrong OS. E.G I'm on Kali I saw something about bsd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing an alternate window manager in Kali first, like Mate or XFCE? That may be better than totally ditching your distro to go with Ubuntu.

Comment: It's the desktop itself.
Not the file manager (not sure the name of atm)

Comment: File manager is not a window manager. When you say desktop, Kali comes with gnome shell which is a window manager, as is mate. If gnome is broken, try another window manager to see if you can get functional.